# Laravel Handling Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my view in my input value field I am using  `{{ old('facebook', $siteSocialData->facebook)}}` and in my controller I have the below code.

Is there a way that I can hide the offset DB error if there is no data in the DB?  Currently the db is empty.

**Controller:**

```
    $siteSocialSettingsDB    = socialSettings::get();
    $siteSocialSettingsData  = $siteSocialSettingsDB[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write:

```
$siteSocialSettingsDB::first();
```

it returns an instance of the model if exists, and null if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks,  That has fixed my issue however do I need to treat my code differently from using `::get()`?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, they are different objects. get() brings you a collection  (like an array) of instances of your model. first() returns a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

firstOrFail() might be helpful.
If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user, so it is not necessary to write explicit checks to return 404 responses when using this method.